# Signed APK fails to install the second time

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I generated APK by doing following in Android Studio: Build -> Generate Signed apk

I copied this APK in Phone's memory and launched it. It installed fine, but only for the first time. I then uninstalled the existing app and launched the same APK again, now it says "App Not Installed".

If I copy the same APK from my computer to this phone again, then again it cannot be installed anymore on this device.
I don't want to do with Play protect off on the device.
Is there a solution to installable the apk all the time?

Comment: without Play protect off you can't install it

Comment: why? When we have to distribute an app to client or to user (without playstore), so all use need to close play protect?

Comment: Yes. Without disabling it the apps will not install.

Answer (score 0):

Go to [link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/protectappeals) And fill out the form. After about two weeks, if the app is OK, your problem will be resolved.

The web service protocol must be HTTPS.

Access permissions must be for a reason.
Etc